# Global route for all ApiControllers in .Net 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0, webapi

In all of my projects i put this code in top my controllers :

```
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult GetTest1()
    {
        return Ok();
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult GetTest2()
    {
        return Ok();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult PostTest1(string Request)
    {
        return Ok("value was " + Request);
    }
}
```

So i can call my APIs with action name without specify each action route, Like below picture from my swagger :

[image]

This work fine but i need to put this route top of all my ApiControllers in my project, **When i decide to change all of my route to new one, i need to replace all RouteAttributes in my project**.

I look for global solution, for Example something like this in my program.cs file :

```
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "api/{controller}/{action}");
```

Problem is i can't make this code work when i delete RouteAttribute from my APIs.

Comment: Why would you get tired of typing `[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]` on every control but not get weary of typing `HttpPost`, `[HttpGet]` annotations on the methods? C'mon...

Comment: @MosiaThabo My issue was about route, But if you have better way to specify Get or Post for each method, i'm all ears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I search few hours for this and after all i didn't find any simple solution for creating good, simple, fast global route for APIs, Then i tried on my own.

**Solution 1 :**
You can create a base class for your APIs and put your route in that file, Then you only inherit from that class in all of your APIs.

APIBase.cs file :

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
public class APIBase: ControllerBase
{
}
```

Next step : If you need have id (or any other parameter) in your URL so you should add RouteAttribute only for that method.

ValuesController.cs file :

```
public class ValuesController : APIBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult GetTest1()
    {
        return Ok();
    }
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{id?}")]
    public IActionResult GetTest2(int id)
    {
        return Ok("value was " + id);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult PostTest1(string Request)
    {
        return Ok("value was " + Request);
    }
}
```

**Edit :**

**Solution 2 :** You can create a string const in your project and use it in all APIs (Suggested by @Serge)

HelperStatic.cs file :

```
public static class HelperStatic
{
    public const string BaseAPIRoute = "api/[controller]/[action]";
}
```

ValuesController.cs file :

```
[ApiController]
[Route(HelperStatic.BaseAPIRoute)]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult GetTest1()
    {
        return Ok();
    }
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{id?}")]
    public IActionResult GetTest2(int id)
    {
        return Ok("value was " + id);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult PostTest1(string Request)
    {
        return Ok("value was " + Request);
    }
}
```

And your swagger will be like this (on both solution) :

[image]

Comment: Instead of adding just one line [Route("api/[controller]/[action]")] you added the whole base controller with the same line. Made just a string const if you have nothing else to do

Comment: @Serge Well it's useful if you decide change your routes all at once, That exactly i needed to do in one of my project, Then i had to change 30 APIs file.

Comment: This is what I was advising you -  define a global const "api/[controller]/[action]" and use it everywhere you want

Comment: @Serge Actually It's not bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

Just followed this simple tutorial on [Global route Prefix](https://www.strathweb.com/2016/06/global-route-prefix-with-asp-net-core-mvc-revisited/) You will as well have to remove the route prefix on top of the controller after adding the global route prefix to your program.cs file.

my swagger :
[image]

my progam.cs

```
 builder.Services.AddMvc(opt =>
 {
     opt.UseCentralRoutePrefix(new RouteAttribute("core/v1/[controller]/[action]"));
 }

).AddControllersAsServices().AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, But i find this "Global Route Prefix" almost 2 years ago, But i didn't complex thing like this because when you try to explain your project to someone else, It's painful. I know your method working but add more time than put Route on top of all APIs.